# Cache problem when adding data sources to the apollo config option in Keystone 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, apollo-server, keystonejs

When executing a request to the server **for the second time**, the result that returns is always the cached one, even if the first request mutated the entity.

here is the `dataSources.js` file that imports two instances of each class of dataSource:

1. legacyUserApi = new LegacyUserApi();
2. legacyMailApi = new LegacyMailApi();

```js
import legacyUserApi from './LegacyUserApi';
import legacyMailApi from './LegacyMailApi';

export default () => ({
  legacyUserApi,
  legacyMailApi
});
```

and in the `keystone.js` file I import it:

```js
import dataSources from './dataSources';

const apps = [
  new GraphQLApp({
    apiPath: API_PATH,
    apollo: {
      dataSources,
      introspection: isDev
    }
  })
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystone js uses `Apollo Server` so I've looked at their [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/):

> Apollo Server calls this function for every incoming operation.
> Also as shown, the function should **create a new instance** of each data source for each operation.

so `dataSources.js` file should import the **class** and not the **instance** so that Apollo Server will create a new instance with every request.

```js
import LegacyUserApi from './LegacyUserApi';
import LegacyMailApi from './LegacyMailApi';

export default () => ({
  legacyUserApi: new LegacyUserApi(),
  legacyMailApi: new LegacyMailApi()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [many ways caching can be used](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching) on top of Apollo Server but your question doesn't indicate which you're using. Ultimately, most of them set a [`Cache-Control` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) on the HTTP response so let's assume that's the case here.

This header is interpreted by both the browser and any shared caches that sit between it and the server, such as a CDN or proxy. Once a cached, the server generally doesn't have any mechanism to invalidate the stored copy. This can be mitigated by setting the correct header directives for the response that will initially be cached. For example, including the `must-revalidate` directive or setting a short `max-age`.

Alternatively, setting the `private` directive will only allow the request to be cached in the browser. Subsequent HTTP requests could then specify `max-age=0, no-cache` to force the data to be fetched again (for example, after a mutation was made). This may allow you to solve your problem for individual users but, obviously, you loose the benefits of a shared cache.

It's difficult to give specific advice without knowing more about your caching configuration, infrastructure and the requests being made. Maybe you can update your question with a reproduction using curl? That'll let you isolate the server behaviour from that of the browser.